# How to describe a person with no criminal record?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The only word I know to describe such a person is *clean*. I tried to find out an adjective or a phrase that explicitly talks about criminal record, but couldn't succeed.

Examples:

> - There is no criminal record, he/she is + *adjective*.
> - There is no criminal record, he/she is + *phrase* (e.g. *adverb* + *adjective*).

Is there such an adjective or a phrase?

Comment: If one has a “clean criminal record,” then there wouldn’t be a criminal record to begin with! You get a record only when you commit a crime.

Comment: @TheWordsmith The examples are already in parallel with that, but should I update the title ("clean" -> "no")?

Comment: Yes. I would substitute the “clean” for “no” or “without a.”

Comment: Your term *clean* works well in the context of a discussion about criminal records.

Comment: Upstanding? The trouble is that lack of a criminal record could mean also a person is just clever enough not to get caught.

Comment: What is wrong with simply saying "They have no criminal record"? I think that using terms like "clean", tends to start from a presumption that they would have such a record.

Comment: The immaculate satisfy your need?

Comment: @ubihatt It seems to be the best option so far.

Comment: Oh great! if you find it interesting, than you can accept it in future, if not now. Good luck! :)

Comment: I've come across the term "cleanskin" to mean a person without a criminal record, but is only found in Collins and Oxford and are labelled either slang or informal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[clean](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clean)**

> adjective (HONEST)
>   ​**C2 honest or fair, or showing that you have not done anything illegal:**
>   
>   *The judge took the defendant's clean record (= the absence of previous involvement in crime) into account when passing sentence.*
>   
>   *I've always had a clean driving licence.*

The first cited use case should be enough to show that *clean* does work, although in qualifying the noun "record" not "defendant."

To extend the meaning to the person, we can use the sense of "**[17. 
honourable or respectable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clean)**."

Comment: Not a great word in my opinion to describe the person rather than the record. If I hear a policeman say "he's clean" I take that to mean they've just searched him for drugs and/or weapons and found none. I don't take it to mean that they've never committed a crime. Unfortunately your references don't seem to back me up, as they conflate the two. From Cambridge: "*not doing anything illegal, or not having or carrying illegal drugs or stolen goods*", and from Collins definition 20: "*a. innocent; not guilty b. not carrying illegal drugs, weapons, etc*".

Comment: @AndyT Sometimes usage pulls up secondary senses into the mainstream and the primary meaning may become obscure. Today the news is all about drugs, not so much about "clean" and honest gentlemen.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [law-abiding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/law-abiding) is the term you want. It doesn’t exactly mean “of someone without a criminal record,” but it does mean the person the term is describing isn’t a criminal. (Which is, essentially, the same thing.)

So, you can say, “He/She has no criminal record; he/she is law-abiding [OR] he/she is a law-abiding citizen.”

Comment: Not what I imagined, but maybe the closest one.

Comment: @ahmedus It’s the best I could come up with. Sorry. :-)

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. :)

Comment: It is my firm conviction that "doesn’t exactly mean" should be "doesn't at all mean". I may currently be reformed and law-abiding, but that does not guarantee that I don't have a long rap sheet from my dark and evil past. But perhaps, having never been convicted, and thus being unconvicted, your convictions differ.

Comment: @mickeyf “Doesn’t exactly mean” is an idiomatic way of speaking. And I’m not sure what you are trying to say. If a person never committed a crime, then this person will not have a record. If a person commits a crime, even after being rehabilitated, this persons *will* have a record.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the compound word "squeaky-clean" means this.  Detective Smith asked, "What does this guy's rap sheet look like?"  Detective Jones replied, "He doesn't have a rap sheet!  He's squeaky-clean!"

Comment: Good idea, but not a good answer (within the parameters of this site) unless you add references.

Answer (score 0):

As a single word, *unconvicted* taken in its plain meaning of *not convicted* would be at least in the ballpark, although depending on context it's not an exact fit. (For example, in the UK it's possible to acquire a criminal record without a conviction by *accepting a caution*, a process which is intended to reduce the workload of the courts).

I must add the qualification that many examples of use (I've looked at the British National Corpus, the Corpus of Contemporary American English, and a few pages of Internet search results) either form part of a noun phrase such as *unconvicted prisoners/detainees* or refer in context to people accused of a crime. Therefore it might not have the right subtext in contexts where the emphasis is on the person described being an upstanding member of society.

On the other hand, unconvicted.com is a website for a law firm specialising in getting criminal records expunged in Kentucky, so at least for them it has the desired connotation.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard this phrase many many times on TV shows, and it's used exclusively in formal context, that is in court, by legal professions:

> **lack of prior criminal conduct** (the word *conduct* can be replaced with the word *record*)
>   = lack of conduct that breaks a law where a criminal penalty can apply. [source](https://www.nfplaw.org.au/criminalconduct)

EXAMPLES:

- Given your **lack of prior criminal conduct**. I am inclined toward probation.
- My guess is that the man **has no prior criminal record**.

Answer (score -1):

> a person with no criminal record
>
> "There is no criminal record, he/she is _______"

- honorable
- trustworthy
- law-abiding
- obedient
- civil

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps the word "**Immaculate**"(adjective).

It means,

> free from stain or blemish; completely neat and clean; without fault or error.

For an example, on the [Kuwait news agency website](https://www.kuna.net.kw/ArticlePrintPage.aspx?id=2271097&language=en) they write:

> The statement listed the requirements for the would-be candidates for seats in the parliament, among which being the necessity to have a Kuwaiti citizenship, be able to read and write, be at least 30 years of age, and have an **immaculate** criminal record.

Another example for an online [job opening](https://www.aciesinternational.com/careers/):

> To be able to provide our clients with the best services, we are looking for men and women with:
>
> 1. A background as described under 1.
> 2. A very specific skillset as described under 2.
> 3. The right attitude as described under 3.
> 4. An **immaculate** criminal record

Or yet another example from 
[Malta today news papers](http://backoffice.maltatoday.com.mt/news/court_and_police/57724/jurors_told_prosecution_did_not_collect_key_evidence_in_2009_holdup) :

> 'The prosecution is telling you to disbelieve a person with an **immaculate** criminal record and to believe a person with ten previous convictions, many of them for theft!'

Considering your example, you can tweak it little bit to say:

> **She/he has *an immaculate* criminal record.**

Comment: The OP is looking for "*an adjective or a phrase that explicitly talks about criminal record*", not a synonym for *clean*.

Comment: @AndyT So, what is immaculate? where you get those adjective from???? Your downvote is unnecessary. Tell me why immaculate can't be the candidate?

Comment: @AndyT "There is no criminal record, he/she is immaculate." or "She/he has immaculate criminal record." **Point me**, if you can't find context in these two sentences.

Comment: @AndyT You are correct that without context word may loose intended meaning, but I'll be happy to help you, if you missed the context in those sentences.

Comment: @AndyT so you backpaddle on context issue, right? Secondly, it is not about you and me, it is about what OP wants. He is okay with my answer, have you happen to read his comment on my answer?!? You need to understand that voting is not done on bases of opinion, it is done on legitimacy of answer. I am not point hungry, I am not converting it into crypto currency. I am just trying to help someone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81385/discussion-between-andyt-and-ubi-hatt).

Comment: You left chat abruptly without explaining your stand point. Anyways, let that be! I'll keep watch next time.

Comment: The connotations of 'immaculate', at least in European culture, have to do with a moral ledger of infractions rather than a criminal report. That is, the Roman Catholic 'Virgin Mary' is so very closely associated with being 'immaculate' that it would be very incongruous to call Dudley Doright of the RCMP so.

Comment: @Mitch you should go with more general meaning. Rest of the world may not know what you are saying (including me). That's very biased way of looking at it. What standard English dictionaries say in Europe?

Comment: @ubihatt that's not how words work. If you use a word, the hearer ascribes to the use  all those connotations whether you intended one version or another. That's how connotations work. Dictionary definitions aren't like a programming API.

Comment: @Mitch believe me, I know, how word works. If you happen to see, then one example is from Kuwait news agency and other from Malta new agency, so do you think they are misusing the word?

Comment: @Mitch Immaculate connotes a person without sin or crime depending upon context when you want to indicate someone has spotless character -- so, it depends upon the context. I disagree with your parochial context limited to Europe. Check my yesterday's answer where one user had problem with word "niggard/niggardly" because they were from U.S. 2 other users counter argued to that user in comment section [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459429/another-word-for-someone-who-says-everything-is-theirs/459430#459430)

Comment: @ubihatt Re: Kuwait and Malta examples - those are great examples and perfectly well used ... _for a different use_. The OP is asking for "There is no criminal record, he/she is ___.". The examples are 'He __has__ an immaculate __criminal record'. The latter is perfectly fine. To say baldly 'a person is immaculate' sounds off, and doesn't imply immediately anything about their criminal record but rather more likely about their sexual experience. And if you are really suggesting 'They have a _ADJ_ criminal record' is what is desired then 'no criminal record' is obviously the best

Comment: @Mitch don't you think that answer should be more specific to OP's need? meaning of the word change in the given context.

Comment: @ubihatt Yes, I think that it is appropriate to give the OP what is best, not necessarily exactly what they ask for. But then you should explicitly say that the exact phrasing of the OP isn't felicitous and that they should use your suggestion as 'They _have_ an __immaculate__ criminal record".

Comment: @Mitch ok, agreed. I have done necessary changes.  Deleted OP's example using immaculate, rather suggested to use it other way round.