# Another word for someone who says everything is theirs

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What is a word for someone who says everything is his unless you pay half of it. My bf and I have been together for 3 years and I always sleep on one side of the bed and so I call it my side and he said that it’s not my side because I didn’t buy the bed. It’s his.

Comment: A word for someone like that? How about a [“cad.”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cad) (Also, I would break up with this cad if I were you, unless, of course, he’s being sarcastic.)

Comment: What kind of meaning are you looking for? For instance, *peevish*, *humorous*,  or *literal*?

Comment: I'd call him an "***ex***"

Comment: Sad to say but your bf is right, technically. He is just stating a fact. But tell him that friendship is not about technicalities or terminology but, well, "friendship," which he needs to **define better** for himself.

Comment: That btw turns this into an OT, though. Oops.

Comment: What I would say to him is:  goodby

Comment: Relationship issues aside, what sort of word are you looking for?  Per the tag description for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), _to ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used._  Also, was he joking, in which case you're looking for something amusing to call him?  Or was he serious and you want something to put in the restraining order?

Comment: "Stupidly pedantic"?

Comment: As Roger says, we need an example sentence. This will help us to know whether you want an adjective or a noun.

Comment: @AndyT The question clearly asks for a noun, although in its absence she could make do with an adj + n phrase.

Comment: @Ily - "a word for x" is not necessarily asking for a noun. I've seen enough SWRs where it seemed obvious to me that the OP was looking for a noun, and it turned out they wanted an adjective. That's the reason we ask for example sentences.

Comment: I didn't know giving unsolicited relationship advice was in this site's wheelhouse.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that there are any exact words to express this idea in English. Usually possession is fairly loose in English. We often use "have" or "my" for association, rather than actual ownership.

As such, one word you could use for him is "Pedantic", which means overly concerned with minor details or rules. "Pedantic" is often used for people who criticize the little things people say (such as "my side of the bed") because of a technicality (real or imagined). Especially if he often corrects little things you say for pointlessly small reasons, "pedantic" is probably a good word to use.

> I told my friend to stop being so *pedantic* after he pointed out my third split infinitive.

Another good word, to point out that he is obsessed with owning things, is "materialistic". Quite simply, he's too focused on material things, and not enough on the important things.

> Jack was so materialistic that, when he got into an accident, he cared more about his car than the other people.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that he is being a **scrooge** (as opposed to Scrooge)

> In the English language, a scrooge – with a lowercase “s” – is a person who is unwilling to give to others. Others words with the same meaning are miserly and stingy. Scrooges are selfish, and not just at Christmas time or the holidays. Here is an example sentence: “Her father is such a **scrooge**."

[Source](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/dont-be-a-scrooge/3108975.html)

Answer (score 0):

He has a trait of both being a [**niggard**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/niggard) and [**inconsiderate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconsiderate). So, you say, he is **niggardly inconsiderate**.

**niggardly:** [*Niggard and nigger **<sub>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22)</sub>** are etymologically unrelated words.*]

> Ungenerous with money, time, etc.; mean.
>
> > ‘he accused the Government of being unbelievably niggardly’

**Inconsiderate**:

> careless of the rights or feelings of others
>
> > ‘it's inconsiderate of her to go away without telling us’

Here is an other example,

My boyfriend is a lot of fun and we get on really well, but he can be really selfish and **niggardly inconsiderate**.

Comment: I would go with inconsiderate. He isn't being stingy in that she still presumably gets to sleep in the bed.  BTW, *not* sleeping in the bed for a few nights might fix the problem...

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 yep! :)

Comment: This doesn't capture the situation described in the question. Yes, the behaviour is inconsiderate, but being inconsiderate can take many forms. Specifically, the word does not reflect the materialistic nature of the inconsiderateness described.

Comment: @JJJ how about niggardly inconsiderate?

Comment: @ubihatt that might work, you could edit your question to add that. :)

Comment: How badly do you want this poor girl to be misunderstood? or to end the relationship? 'Stingy' [is a lot safer than 'niggardly', which has literally cost jobs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22) It has its own Wikipedia page on why you shouldn't use it, except to be SNOOTy about preserving archaic word choices.

Comment: @lly you are right on niggardly, can't be use. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, *niggard* has absolutely nothing to do with *nigger.* While the derivation is uncertain, it's probably from Early Scandinavian (cf Norwegian *nøgg,* Swedish *njugg*) or the Old English cognate *hnēaw,* stingy. [OED]

Comment: @JJJ thanks for support on "niggard". I have updated my answer :) and it is final now!

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, you are correct. I was bit confuse with what lIy connoted. I have updated my answer and it is final version :)

Comment: @JJJ upvote Andrew's comment and changed in description.

Comment: I had a small wobble about the word niggardly and found it is ok https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22

Comment: @WendyG :) I tried my best to clear doubts of those who objected in comment section, but I failed, hence zero UV (hehehe). I shouted on the top of my voice that they are unrelated..... Anyways, yeah! thanks you paid attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the word **[possessive](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/possessive_1)**? Oxford Learner's Dictionary defines it as

> not liking to lend things or share things with others

```
Example: Jimmy's very possessive about his toys.
```

Comment: Yeah, that definitely works, although in the context of a relationship you should note that 'Jimmy's very possessive' normally means he's possessive *of the girl herself* and often gets foolishly or violently jealous. She'd have to say 'he's possessive of the bed' or 'of his things' every time it came up in conversation.

Comment: In that case, there are a few words to look up in thesaurus.com, including grabby, and acquisitive.

Comment: 'My bf is grabby' would again mean he likes to grab *my body*; 'he's acquisitive' would mean he goes out to acquire *new* things, not that he's possessive of the old ones. Like I said, possessive does work; it's just that in the terms of a relationship it usually means something else so you have to phrase it a certain way.

Comment: How can it be "possessive"? After all, the bed **does** belong to him, doesn't it?

Comment: You have a point, @Kris. But I thought one can be possessive about the things they own. Am I wrong? Please correct me if so.

Comment: Yes, one can be. However, that's when it's beyond reasonable limits, to the point of being abnormal. If he did not share the bed at all, then that could be possessiveness. Denying that one side belongs to someone else is not. Right? :D

Comment: @Kris See my answer below. **It *is* beyond reasonable limits** to start a fight with one's SO over formal ownership rights when all she is doing is proclaiming a preference and use right for one side. He is being possessive; it's just not the best word *in isolation* since it has a different meaning when used to describe a boyfriend.

Comment: It's actually worse if he does share it: he's arguing and causing relationship trouble over something that's not actually greatly important to him. That's why I think the real issue is either a feeling of being unappreciated or disrespected or an Asperger-like insistence on formal logic without any attention paid to its interpersonal affects.